# method_exist для трейтов

Tags: php, yii2, traits

В Yii2 есть понятие behaviors, подключение к модели которого добавляет к классу функции, описанные в этом behavior.

А можно ли проверить для объекта is_callable или method_exists наличие этого метода? Ведь метод не описан явно в классе, а внедрен через behavior.

Comment: а при чем тут трейты? функционал то схож, конечно, но одно поддерживается на уровне языка, а другое на уровне фреймворка

Comment: вам похоже сюда -> [`hasMethod`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-component.html#hasMethod()-detail)

Comment: Точно, hasMethod

Comment: оформил ответом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очевидно, что в том время как трейты являются стандартным средством расширения функционально классов на уровне языка, то behaviours являеются надстройкой фреймворка. В связи с этим знаниями и инструментариями о том имеется ли у объекта данный метод, должен обладать сам объект, к которому поведение подключается. То есть если класс может подключать поведения, то, очевидно, должен знать какие поведения подключены, и какими методами они его наделяют.

Для определения, имеет ли компонент метод, полученный от поведения, используйте [`Component::hasMethod()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-component.html#hasMethod()-detail)

> Returns a value indicating whether a method is defined.
>   A method is defined if:
>    -   the class has a method with the specified name
>    -   an attached behavior has a method with the given name (when $checkBehaviors is true).

т.е. `hasMethod()` определяет наличие искомого метода среди членов класса, а также среди методов подключенных поведений.

*зы: познакомился с Yii :D*